# create a bottom bar in android by using actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

hi  I am new to this android programming .I have included actionbarsherlock in my project.
I want to add a bottom bar to my all activities in common. Can anyone suggest me agood tutorial for creating a bottom bar

Comment: Could you tell us what do you intend to put in this bar? I have a project in which I implemented a "status bar" in the bottom of all activities, using only Fragments.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock is a back port of the native action bar API. It is not an arbitrary widget with which you can do whatever you want. It can only do what the native action bar can do.

Comment: @hsgubert hi i want to to implement something like that for all the activities So. can you please suggest any tutorial for it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've just seen that ActionBarSherlock is actually implemented with Fragments, so you have two options:

1. Use ActionBarSherlock. In this case I would follow the tutorial http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html and look at samples described in http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html
2. Implement your own bar using Fragments, if you want to customize it more (or use it for other ends). In this case I would follow the tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

As a general tip, I recommend the site http://www.vogella.com/android.html. It has great tutorials about a wide range of subjects in Android programming.