# How place ActionBarSherlock at the bottom?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and I need to place it at the bottom.

Is there any way to do this?

Can I just set `android:gravity="bottom"` in style.xml?

Comment: So, did you tried `android:gravity="bottom"`?

Comment: Check this stackoverflow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102104/create-a-bottom-bar-in-android-by-using-actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot change the position of the `ActionBarSherlock`. It will always be displayed on the top. However, you can easily put your tabs and other contents you add in the `ActionBar` to be displayed at the bottom.

I also had a similar problem. I solved it by putting `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` within the `<activity>` tag.

For example, this worked:

```
<activity android:name=".my.Activity" 
          android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
```

However, only in portrait mode it will actually show at the bottom of the screen. So, you will have to define your application orientation in the manifest as portrait, otherwise it will again go to the top.

Comment: I have done it but I have only two tabs and it doesn't work for me.